# Twitter Buttons: Data-Text

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to update the "data-text" attribute of a twitter share button, but I'm not doing very well so far. Here is a link to my pen on codepen.io: [my pen](http://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/full/WxLOVA/)

Here is the important code:

HTML

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="me" data-hashtags="quotes" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

jQuery

```
$(".twitter-share-button").attr("data-text", "You");
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

your document HTML structure wouldn't be the same after including the twitter widgets.js file, so try to include it just after your javascript code like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="me" data-hashtags="quotes" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".twitter-share-button").attr("data-text", "You");
</script>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```